# Error Adding Magento 2 SOAP Service Reference With Visual Studio

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add Magento 2 as a service reference to Visual Studio 2013.

I add the address http://mage2.dev/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1

But every time I click ok, I get an error that says.

There was an error downloading '{https://}mage2.dev/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '{https://}mage2.dev/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1'.
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

It seems as though I need to authorize first to get the wsdl, but I can't authorize because I don't have the wsdl. Feels like a chicken and egg problem.

Am I on the right track? What do I need to do to add the service reference?

Comment: Same issue if you want to test with SOAP UI app.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have exactly the same issue. Thx.

Comment: We ended up disabling authentication on the SOAP API to gain access to the WSDL. You will need to edit the Magento source code to do this. Once we had access to the WSDL we could use Visual Studio to add the service reference. After that you should be able to enable authentication since VS already has the WSDL.